# Code to get RAM usage in blackberry?

Tags: memory, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

There is way to calculate memory usage in blackberry java, but i want to get RAM usage stats in blackberry. Is there any code for the same?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: It depends upon the operating system.

Comment: I am using Blackberry os 7.0 and below. So, is it possible in that?

Comment: check this - http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/05/get-memory-usage-in-bb.html